# Py2Exe won't successfully compile the pygame.font module on Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, pygame, py2exe

I made a program using the pygame module on Python 3 and it works fine within python, but when I try to compile is using py2exe it won't run. (I just get the programName.exe has stopped working error upon trying to run it).

I managed to narrow down this problem to the pygame.font module as when I comment all the lines that use that module everything works fine. I tried to forcefully include the module using the -i flag in py2exe, but it doesn't appear to change anything...

What am I doing terribly wrong?

Edit: I managed to get the reason of the program not working - it crashes as it can not find build\executable.exe\pygame\freesansbold.ttf . What I don't understand is why the hell is the pygame folder supposed to be located in a folder with the name of my executable? (Of course, I can not create a folder with the same name as an existing file in the directory). If anyone has a clue to how to fix it, please help!!

Comment: python was not designed to create exe file - so there is no easy and effective method.

Comment: I know, but is the above problem a bug in the py2exe module, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Tell me the error message and I can fix it. I had the same problem with cx_Freeze. It was a simple fix I just don't remember what I did and if you paste the error message I'll figure it out.

Comment: I got it posting answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using cx_Freeze, so hopefully this will work for you as well. Open up your pygame package folder. It should be `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pygame`. There should be a True Type Font File titled freesansbold.ttf. Copy that file then open the folder containing your exe program. There should be a zipped file called library. Open it up and go to the pygame folder inside the zipped file. Should look something like this `\build\exe.win32-3.4\library.zip\pygame`. And just paste the freesansbold.ttf file in that folder and it should work perfectly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.... where should the zipped file named library be? I didn't really get that part.

Comment: I don't know if there is one for py2exe, but there is one for cx_Freeze could post a screen shot of all the files in the executable folder or just list them?

Comment: @VladimirShevyakov Nvm I just used py2exe real quick and it should be in the `dist` folder

Comment: Sorry for the lengthy response time... the files in the executable folder are: executable.exe , libiomp5md.dll , MSVCR100.dll , SDL.dll , SDL_image.dll , SDL_mixer.dll, SDL_ttf.dll , smpeg.dll

Comment: where should the freesansbold.ttf go?

Comment: In the library zip folder which should be in the dist folder. If there is a pygame folder inside the library folder put it there if not just stick it in the library zip folder.

Comment: No problem glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way! By including `-l library.zip` argument in the build_exe command and then following the instructions given by DeliriousSyntax in the answer above I managed to get it to work!